# TI CC3200: How to get access point list(Wifi Direct)

Tags: texas-instruments

How to get available wifi direct accesspoint list in TI cc3200 launchpad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to get available wifi direct accesspoint list?**

An example of fetching max 10 results:

```
            Sl_WlanNetworkEntry_t netEntries[10];
            _i16 resultsCount = sl_WlanGetNetworkList(0,10,&netEntries[0]);
            for(i=0; i< resultsCount; i++)
            {
                  printf("%s\n",netEntries[i].ssid);
            }
```

Now you have rssi of all the visible APs. From the netEntries array, you can get rssi of the AP you are connected to.

Source:- https://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless_connectivity/simplelink_wifi_cc31xx_cc32xx/f/968/t/357258#pi239031350=1

Can you please explain what exactly you want to do in your second question ??

Comment: Thank you, It answered my question.